# Can not update release definition through API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

It  seems like I can no longer update a VSRM release definition through the API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/definitions/update?view=vsts-rest-5.0

The only thing I changed was the version number from `11` to `12` after get release definition.

> API URL: https://.vsrm.visualstudio.com/One/_apis/Release/definitions?api-version=5.0-preview.3
>
> Response:
>   {
>       "$id": "1",
>       "innerException": null,
>       "message": "You are using an old copy of release definition. Refresh your copy and try again.",
>       "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data",
>       "typeKey": "InvalidRequestException",
>       "errorCode": 0,
>       "eventId": 3000
>   }

I tried both, the `4.1` and the `5.0` preview api versions. Same error.
I use PostMan with PAT. GET works fine.

Can you please tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not modify the revision. Submit a modified version of the release definition with the old revision and the server will generate a new version number for the new version.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer.